# How to give text overflow ellipsis to collapse header in Ant design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant design Collapse , I want ellipsis for collapse header when text overflow

I used like this but it didn't work can some one help me in this?

```
.ant-collapse-header{
width:50px
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below CSS, it must work. However you don't need width attribute if you want that to be scaled for full width but without new line.

```
.ant-collapse-header {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[image]